# Can I sum a value over different times in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, group-by

I have a Dataframe that looks like this

| WEEK | DELIVERY_BOY_ID | TOTAL_GMV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-04 | 999999999.0 | 470510.11 |
| 2022-04-11 | 999999999.0 | 557351.02 |
| 2022-04-18 | 999999999.0 | 454225.78 |
| 2022-04-25 | 999999999.0 | 527932.46 |
| 2022-05-02 | 999999999.0 | 556741.18 |
| 2022-05-09 | 999999999.0 | 524571.93 |
| 2022-05-16 | 999999999.0 | 547195.66 |
| 2022-05-23 | 999999999.0 | 112423.49 |

What I'm trying to do is to sum the TOTAL_GMV every 4 weeks (sum from week 2022-05-02 to 2022-05-23, sum from 2022-04-25 to 2022-05-16 and so on for every week), and to show me the result with the date of the last week that was summed

So, the final result should look something like this:

| WEEK | DELIVERY_BOY_ID | TOTAL_GMV | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-04 | 999999999.0 | ********* | Sum from 2022-03-14 to 2022-04-04 |
| 2022-04-11 | 999999999.0 | ********* | Sum from 2022-03-21 to 2022-04-11 |
| 2022-04-18 | 999999999.0 | ********* | Sum from 2022-03-28 to 2022-04-18 |
| 2022-04-25 | 999999999.0 | 2.010.018,91 | Sum from 2022-04-04 to 2022-04-25 |
| 2022-05-02 | 999999999.0 | 2.096.250,44 | Sum from 2022-04-11 to 2022-05-02 |
| 2022-05-09 | 999999999.0 | 2.063.469,15 | Sum from 2022-04-18 to 2022-05-09 |
| 2022-05-16 | 999999999.0 | 2.156.441,23 | Sum from 2022-04-25 to 2022-05-16 |
| 2022-05-23 | 999999999.0 | 1.639.932,26 | Sum from 2022-05-02 to 2022-05-23 |

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `WEEK` is the index, you can do:

```py
>>> df.TOTAL_GMV.rolling(4).sum()
WEEK
2022-04-04           NaN
2022-04-11           NaN
2022-04-18           NaN
2022-04-25    2010019.37
2022-05-02    2096250.44
2022-05-09    2063471.35
2022-05-16    2156441.23
2022-05-23    1740932.26
Name: TOTAL_GMV, dtype: float64
```

To add it to the df,

```py
df['TOTAL_GMV'] = df.TOTAL_GMV.rolling(4).sum()
```

(If it's not the index, change that to `df.set_index('WEEK').TOTAL_GMV.rolling(4).sum()`.)